# Inherited static methods used with static class variable return NameError

Tags: python

I have two classes:

```
 class BaseService(object):
     @staticmethod
     def say_name:
         return __class_variable__

 class SubClassService(BaseService):
      __class_variable__ = NOLA
```

When I call my static method like so:

```
 SubClassService.say_name()
```

I get a:

```
 NameError: global name '__class_variable__' is not defined
```

Using SQLAlchemy in the past, I figured that I this was something I could do easily, but it turns out they use `@declared_attr` custom decorator among things to enable similar functionality.

Can I do this without resorting to SQLAlchemy like code?

Comment: A `staticmethod` cannot directly reference its containing class. If you need this functionality, use a `classmethod` instead. Alternatively, you can use the fully qualified name (`BaseService.__class_variable__`) to access the class variable. For obvious reasons, this is not ideal.

Comment: No, you cannot do it this way. Convert it to a classmethod and then acess it using the class.

Comment: solved it by making them class methods, passing in class, and then calling it as `cls.__class_variable__`. do either of you want to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Joel Cornett commment above:

> A staticmethod cannot directly reference its containing class. If you need this functionality, use a classmethod instead. Alternatively,
>   you can use the fully qualified name (BaseService.**class_variable**)
>   to access the class variable. For obvious reasons, this is not ideal.